# Postgresql 10 xpath return null array

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

I'm trying to read an XML using xpath:

```
WITH tbl as (
    SELECT  '<name_space xmlns="http://path/to/ns/name_space" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://path/to/ns/name_space http://path/to/ns/name_space.xsd" datatype="datatype" generation_time="2018-04-06T15:56:00+02:00" start_time="2018-04-06T15:50:00+02:00" end_time="2018-04-06T15:55:00+02:00" source="sourcename">
  <ele0>
    <c_ele0/>
  </ele0>
  <ele1 prop1="12345" prop2="67890" prop3="a text" prop4="55" prop5="a text" prop6="12.345" prop7="6.789" prop8="86" prop9="5">
    <c_ele1 prop10="264.00" prop11="21.49"/>
  </ele1>
</name_space>' as cnt::xml)
SELECT xpath('//text()', cnt) FROM tbl;
```

In this case the query return the following result:

```
{"  ","    ","  ","  ","    ","  ",""}
```

I've tried different combination, searching for 
'//name_space/text()', '//name_space/ele0/text()', '//name_space/ele1/text()', 'ele1/text()', '//name_space/ele1/@prop1/text()' 
... but the result is always a null string.

I need to extract properties values in the root and for each element.
What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are all the preperties:

```
t=# WITH tbl as (
    SELECT  '<name_space xmlns="http://path/to/ns/name_space" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://path/to/ns/name_space http://path/to/ns/name_space.xsd" datatype="datatype" generation_time="2018-04-06T15:56:00+02:00" start_time="2018-04-06T15:50:00+02:00" end_time="2018-04-06T15:55:00+02:00" source="sourcename">
  <ele0>
    <c_ele0/>
  </ele0>
  <ele1 prop1="12345" prop2="67890" prop3="a text" prop4="55" prop5="a text" prop6="12.345" prop7="6.789" prop8="86" prop9="5">
    <c_ele1 prop10="264.00" prop11="21.49"/>
  </ele1>
</name_space>'::xml as cnt)
SELECT xpath('//*/*/@*', cnt) FROM tbl;
                               xpath
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 {12345,67890,"a text",55,"a text",12.345,6.789,86,5,264.00,21.49}
(1 row)
```